# A/B Testing an AMP script

Tags: ads, amp-html, ab-testing

I need to test a amp script of an ad (tag < amp-ad >), but in AMP documentation I have only find ways to test style changes between the two versions tested.

Does anyone when through something similar? How did you implemented a A/B test of a amp script?

Comment: The complete documentation for amp experiments can be seen here: https://amp.dev/documentation/components/amp-experiment-v1.0/?format=websites

Answer (score 0):

Running an A/B test through an AMP page has to happen via a CMS or server-side experiment due to the nature of AMP pages not being able to load custom Javascript files. A CMS like [Instapage](https://instapage.com/blog/test-amp-pages) will allow you to A/B test an AMP page.